# Sort a js object by key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a js object:

```
{
    "total_builds": 73,
    "history": {
        "2021-2-8": 4,
        "2021-2-5": 39,
        "2021-2-10": 6,
        "2021-2-6": 13,
        "2021-2-7": 14
    }
}
```

and how can i sort it like this:

```
{
    "total_builds": 73,
    "history": {
        "2021-2-5": 39,
        "2021-2-6": 13,
        "2021-2-7": 14,
        "2021-2-8": 4,
        "2021-2-10": 3
    }
}
```

Simply put how to sort a json object by key(date)?

Comment: you're mistaking how objects work with arrays.. the correct answer is `objects dont get sorted`

Comment: Non-array objects aren't meant to be sorted, they *usually* maintain key order but there's no guarantee of stability and no built-in sorting methods. How are you actually using the data? It would probably make more sense to sort it then.

Comment: There are several problems with this.  The first problem you're going to run into is that "history" is not a numeric sort; it is an alphabetic sort.  So you're going to get 2021-2-1, 2021-2-10, 2021-2-2, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to sort an object? That doesn't really make sense to me. object are key value pared so sorting doesn't do anything. Also even if you did sort it that wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Use a real date format, for example 2021-02-05 rather than an imaginary one such as 2021-2-5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could transform `history` to array of key-value pairs, short that pairs, and transform back to object

```js
const a = {
  total_builds: 73,
  history: {
    "2021-2-8": 4,
    "2021-2-5": 39,
    "2021-2-10": 6,
    "2021-2-6": 13,
    "2021-2-7": 14,
  },
};

a.history = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(a.history).sort((a, b) => new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]))
);

console.log(a);
```